# Spring REST response shows raw Java object not the JSON elements

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

In my Spring application I have an Object `FooBar`, REST returns this object when a request made to an endpoint:

```
{
"item":"foo",
"value":"bar"
}
```

But I have created a another Object FooBarMap that has `Map<String, FooBar>`
and another endpoint to return `FooBarMa`, now what I get is something similar:

```
{
"name":"Jimmy",
"foobar":"foobarmap@b7f23d9"
}
```

so in essence I'm getting the raw object, not serialized into JSON

I would expect :

```
{
"name":"Jimmy",
"foobar":{
  "item":"foo",
  "value":"bar"
 }
}
```

Comment: You should include the Java-classes you've made as well.

Comment: Your last JSON is not valid. Update the question with the real response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Map<String, Foobar>` your FooBarMap class should be like below

**FooBarMap**

```
public class FooBarMap{

String name;
FooBar foobar;

//Setter & Getter
}
```

**FooBar**

```
public class FooBar{

String item;
String value;

//setter & getters
}
```

Then during setting FoorBarMap properties you can set FooBar class properties as well.